# Add postmeta to all blog posts

Tags: posts, mysql, post-meta

I have a bunch of blog posts that I need to update with a custom postmeta key/value pair. Therefore I have two questions - where can I find the postmeta entries in a worpdress MySQL database and how can I update all blog posts and add the following postmeta key value pair to them.

```
<wp:postmeta>
    <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[_dt_post_settings]]></wp:meta_key>
    <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:3:{s:6:"layout";s:18:"with-right-sidebar";s:27:"show-standard-sidebar-right";s:4:"true";s:19:"show-featured-image";s:4:"true";}]]></wp:meta_value>
</wp:postmeta>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post meta entries are in your wordpress database, in the wp_postmeta table.

I am just a newbie, not sure if this is right, but something I can think of that might help you in the right direction. Hope this helps.

```
function wordpress_custom_post_meta_bulk()
   {
      $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1) );
      foreach($posts as $p) :  
         $meta += array('_key' => '';
                        '_value' => '';);
         update_post_meta($p->ID, 'meta',true);
      endforeach; 
   }
```